# Let the plane V be defined by $ax + by + cz + d = 0$; with $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}$ and the vector $(a; b; c)$ a unit vector.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, euclidean-geometry

I am battling to get my mind around some of the concepts involving vectors in $3$-space. This question asks me whether the following statements are True or False:

(A) The line $(a; b; c)$ is parallel to $V$

(B) The distance of the plane from the origin is $|d|$

For (A) I don't think I have enough to work with here. I know that if a line is parallel to a plane then it's direction vector must be perpendicular to the planes normal vector... I honestly do not know how to go about proving this and perhaps I am over thinking this.

For (B) I have said this is false as the distance between the plane from the origin is not $|d|$ and is given by the formula:

$$d=\frac{|Ax+By+Cz+D|}{|A^2+B^2+C^2|}$$

I would really appreciate any input on this.

Thanks!

Comment: In part (A), are they talking about the vector (a,b,c) instead of a line?  This is a normal vector to the plane, so it won't be parallel to the plane.  In part (B), you have the right idea, but your formula isn't quite right.

Comment: @Pedro, thanks! I will remove the previous comment and use this @ to notify user84413

Comment: @user84413  
In part (A) they are referring to the line (a,b,c). Re Part (B), where have I gone wrong with my formula? Thank you for your input!

Comment: I'm not quite sure what they mean by the line (a,b,c), unless they mean the line consisting of all multiples of (a,b,c).  In part (B), you need a square root in the denominator, and you want to substitute x=0, y=0, z=0 and use that (a,b,c) is a unit vector.

Comment: I believe they mean the direction vector of the line is $(a, b, c)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For part (A) your reasoning is correct. A line with direction vector $\mathbf{v}$ is parallel to a plane with normal vector $\mathbf{n}$ if and only if $\mathbf{v}$ is orthogonal to $\mathbf{n}$, that is, if and only if $\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{n} = 0$. In this case the direction vector of the line is the same as the normal vector of the plane and so they cannot be parallel since $\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{n} = \mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{n} = 1 \neq 0$.

For part (B) you may use the following argument. Let $\mathbf{u}$ be any point in the plane. Then the distance from the origin to $\mathbf{u}$ is $\|\mathbf{u}\|$. Your goal is to find the minimum value of $\|\mathbf{u}\|$. By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have that

$$
|d| = |\mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{u}| \leq \|\mathbf{n}\|\cdot\|\mathbf{u}\| = \|\mathbf{u}\|
$$

since $\mathbf{n}$ is a unit vector. Therefore the minimum distance of the plane from the origin is bounded below by $|d|$. The last step is to show that there exists a vector in the plane whose norm is $|d|$. In this case such a vector is given by $-d\mathbf{n}$ since

$$
\mathbf{n}\cdot(-d\mathbf{n}) + d = -d\mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{n} +d = -d  +d = 0
$$

and $\|-d\mathbf{n}\| = |d|\|\mathbf{n}\| = |d|$.

Comment: Thanks very much for this detailed explanation! I am not too familiar with Cauchy-Schwarz inequalities so I will need to spend a bit more time on this before it hits home. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, my pleasure. The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality can be useful in a lot of different situations - definitely worth knowing.